# Pythonic way to slice longitude array across meridian

Tags: python, numpy

I am working with oceanic data on a grid where each degree of the earth corresponds to a data point, i.e. I can access a point with `data[lat_index, lon_index]`, where `lat_index` and `lon_index` correspond to a gridpoint latitude and longitude. I also have arrays corresponding to the gridpoints:

```
lat_arr = np.arange(-90,91)
lon_arr = np.arange(0,360)
```

I am looking for a way to slice data across a meridian. For example, I would like to be able to retrieve a slice corresponding to a rectangle corresponding to -20S to 10N and -30W (i.e. 360-30 E) to 30E. Obviously `data[-20:11, 330:31)` does not do the trick since `330:31` retrieves no data. Is there a pythonic way to slice my arrays across the meridian at `lon_index=0`? I am working with large datasets, so efficiency is key and I do not want to create many new arrays.

Comment: np.roll(lon_arr, -30)[-60:] or something similar

Comment: Concatenate 2 (or possibly 4 slices).  Or construct the equivalent index lists (with `np.r`.  `np.r_[330:360,0:30] ` to cover the longitude range.